# Recovery techniques for Spark Streaming scheduling delay

Tags: performance, apache-spark, delay, spark-streaming

We have a Spark Streaming application that has basically zero scheduling delay for hours, but then suddenly it jumps up to multiple minutes and spirals out of control: [image: mounting delay] This is happens after a while even if we double the batch interval.

We are not sure what causes the delay to happen (theories include garbage collection). The cluster has generally low CPU utilization regardless of whether we use 3, 5 or 10 slaves.

We are really reluctant to further increase the batch interval, since the delay is zero for such long periods. Are there any techniques to improve recovery time from a sudden spike in scheduling delay? We've tried seeing if it will recover on its own, but it takes hours if it even recovers at all.

Comment: Is there any errors in the first batch that is causing issue ?

Comment: No, the job has been processing error free.

Answer (score 0):

Open the batch links, and identified which stages are in delay. Are there any external access to other DBs/application which are impacting this delay?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWmsB.png)

Go in each job, and see the data/records processed by each executor. you can find problems here.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsT02.png)

There may be skewness in data partitions as well. If the application is reading data from kafka and processing it, then there can be skewness in data across cores if the partitioning is not well defined. Tune the parameters: # of kafka partitions, # of RDD partitions, # of executors, # of executor cores.